# Is there a bank product similar to a savings account which lowers compounded mortgage interest?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, savings

This is complete hearsay, but someone told me there exists a specific type of "savings account" where the funds deposited count towards a mortgage when interest is calculated.

For instance, if a mortgage is $100000 and $10000 is deposited in this savings account, only $90000 is used in interest calculations.

The closest I can find is [something like this.](http://www.money-rates.com/advancedstrategies/savings/mortgagesavingsaccount.htm)

Comment: Not sure about United States. This is very common in India. It comes with some strings attached.

Comment: I think the usual term is "mortgage offset account".

Comment: Home Equity Lines Of Credit ('HELOCs') may work in a similar fashion. In some ways these are different than a mortgage account, but effectively they give you a limit on how much credit you can have outstanding at one time, and you may be able to set it up so deposits you make to the bank go against that balance. Your interest cost will rise and fall as you increase and decrease the amount of your credit you are drawing down at one time.

Answer (score 7):

Yes they do exist in other parts of the world but probably not the USA.

In Australia they are called a 100% Mortgage Offset Account and are fairly common with most bigger banks and some smaller lenders too. With most of the banks here there are usually no strings attached apart from maybe a small account keeping fee with some.

I think they have a similar product in the UK by the same name and in parts of Asia (maybe under a different name).

Comment: They do exist in the US but they are typically called "money merge accounts." They are not very common.

Comment: @stannous - I have mentioned offset accounts in other questions and most comments from residents of the US is that they have never heard of such a product. Here they are very common and have been common for over a decade.

Answer (score 1):

Mortgage Offset Account is reasonably common in the UK.

Say you have a £100,000 mortgage. And you have a bank account that varies between +£3000 and -£1000. And a savings account that goes up £100 a month. You throw them all together into a Mortgage Offset Account, so your mortgage owed varies between £97,000 and £101,000 every month, plus £100 come off every month, so you pay interest on £97,000 to £101,000 instead of £100,000.